# training validation and test example

Tags: model, validation

I have never used a validation set (I have used test sets, or holdouts). I THINK I understand them, but I have looked EVERYWHERE, and simply cannot find an example with numbers of how the validation changes or modifies the original coefficients (I think that is what it does). can anybody provide an brief example with some numbers (like, "the validation set consisted of 200 observations, and changed the coefficients in this manner". thanks

Comment: What do you mean by changing the coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

> and simply cannot find an example with numbers of how the validation changes or modifies the original coefficients

It doesn't.  You don't refit on the validation set, you fit your model on the training data and then predict on the validation set in order to do model selection or do make sure your model is not overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

it just seems to me that the holdout set is the test for overfitting, inst it?  if you have a small MSE, isnt that really THE test?  so, is it fair to say that the validation set is simply a "pre" test, so to speak, just another check of the model?  but further what is the criteria for determining if we can go on to the test set.. i.e the validation set does not overfit?  thanks